# mongodb 2.4.1 failing with 'process out of memory'

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have the following mongo versions

```
db version v2.4.1    
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.1,
```

and

```
db version v2.2.1-rc1, pdfile version 4.5, 
MongoDB shell version: 2.2.1-rc1
```

installed on `64-bit windows 7` machine.

I have a collection having `10001000` (10 million+) records, when I use V 2.4.1 to aggregate, it fails with the following 
error:

```
Fatal error in CALL_AND_RETRY_2
Allocation failed - process out of memory
```

However when I use V 2.2.1-rc1, to aggregate the same collection, it works fine and gives result in around 1 minute.

Sample document of the collection that is being aggregated:

```
{

    "_id" : ObjectId("516bdd1c39b10c722792e007"),
    "f1" : 10000010,
    "f2" : 10000000,
    "key" : 0
}
```

Aggregation Command:

```
{$group: {"_id": "$key", total: {$sum: "$f1"}}}
```

Command used to populate records:

```
for(var i = 10011000; i < 10041000; ++i)
{ 
    db.testp.insert({"f1": i+10, "f2": i, "key": i%1000})
}
```

Answer (score 4):

How much memory do you have?  Could it be the `$group` is taking up more than 10% of available memory and causing the error?  See the aggregation documentation on [memory for cumulative operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation/#memory-for-cumulative-operators).

**edit 1:**

Out of interest - does the aggregation work outside the shell? eg calling it from a driver.
I have seen similar v8 errors and as the shell was updated to v8 in 2.4  Theres a chance it could be that.

**edit 2:**

If the resulting array is too big in the shell then that can also trigger the error: see [SERVER-8859](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-8859).  To work around you might need to run multiple aggregations, either by doing a `$match` early on to limit the working set or even a `$skip` and `$limit` to paginate through the result set.

I tried your aggregation with 10,070,999 docs on 2.4.1 on a mac and didn't get the error

Comment: Ross, Thanks for the reply.
I have 4GB RAM in my system. 
I had tested with 100,1000, 100000 unique keys (i.e.,  `"_id" = "$key"` in `$group`) It failed in all those cases on `V2.4`. However it worked fine in `V2.2`. I did read about *10%* memory utilization thing earlier; but the same is present in `V2.2` as well. But it works fine on `V2.2`!! The only difference I could read was something to do with `$sort` in *Memory for Cumulative Operators*. I'm not sorting here anyways.

Comment: I'd try it using a driver and see if you are hitting a V8 shell issue.

Comment: Thank you for your time.  
About edit1, I tried the same through pymongo and it worked. I got a reply here as follows:

`Try using the v2.2 shell to connect to the v2.4 mongo db, and see if the error reproduces. I suspect that this error is coming from the shell, not from MongoDB.`

I tried that. That is mongod `V2.4` and mongo `V2.2`. That too worked! Thanks again!

Comment: From whatever I see, wherever mongo `2.4` shell is involved it fails!

Comment: [SERVER-8859](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-8859) Failed for me as well.

Comment: Regarding *edit2*, The business requirement needs auto generation of aggregation code as users can make custom formulae (not very complicated ones, though). So it has to be relatively small and simple. Hence running multiple aggregations and then running another aggregation of them may not be scalable model to automate.

Comment: Ok well if it works through the driver and it works with the old shell (2.2) then it is a manifestation of SERVER-8859.  If you could provide a full test case that would be really helpful in ensuring it does get fixed and whether it is the same issue or just has the same result.  As I said using your test code I couldn't reproduce.